# Extracting X and Y from a GLKVector3 ? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit

Say I have a GLKVector3 and want to read only the x and y values as CGPoints - how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`GLKVector3` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKVector3/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010979-CH3-SW1), there is type definition:

```
union _GLKVector3
{
   struct { float x, y, z; };
   struct { float r, g, b; };
   struct { float s, t, p; };
      float v[3];
};
typedef union _GLKVector3 GLKVector3;
```

There for there are 3 options:

`GLKVector3`'s `v` attribute which is a `float[3]` array of `{x,y,z}`

i.e.:

```
GLKVector3 vector;

...

float x = vector.v[0];
float y = vector.v[1];
float z = vector.v[2];

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

Then there are also float attributes `x,y,z` or less relevant `r,g,b` or `s,t,p` for different uses of the vector type:

```
CGPoint p = CGPointMake(vector.x,vector.y);
```

Answer (score 1):

`GLKVector3` is declared as

```
union _GLKVector3
{
    struct { float x, y, z; };
    struct { float r, g, b; };
    struct { float s, t, p; };
    float v[3];
};
typedef union _GLKVector3 GLKVector3;
```

So the easiest and most readable way to convert is:

```
GLKVector3 someVector;
…
CGPoint somePoint = CGPointMake(someVector.x,someVector.y);
```

Note however that `CGPoint` consist of `CGFloat`s which might be a double in 64-Bit environments.

Comment: Good point about 64-bit -- you'll want to be careful if you need to convert both ways and/or write out data that may be read on a different device architecture.